# what's the meaning of `Executable File `? and the `sloc` of github hint?

Tags: source-code, terminology, python

When I read the [GitHub opensource project code](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks/blob/master/utils/autoban.py):

I see the

```
Executable File  67 lines (60 sloc)  2.42 KB
```

in front of the content.

what's the meaning of `Executable File`? and the `sloc`?

and when I run it in my PyCharm, there seems nothing happening. what's the function of it? how to use the file?

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to be a question about Free Software (or Open Source).

Comment: From your linked example it seems GitHub is counting any non-blank line (including comments) as part of the "sloc" count. Since there are 7 blank lines (including the apparently implicit blank line at the end of the file), the sloc count is 60. As noted in the Wikipedia article linked below, there is not really a standard definition of what counts as 1 "SLOC", so different tools may report this in different ways. There is not even a complete agreement on what counts as a physical line at the end of the file, as you can see from your example (is the file 66 lines or 67?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Executable" means, as you guessed, that you can execute this file directly (i.e., it's not just a library or a collection of functions).
Specifically, this executable is designed to take input from a log being piped in to it. Since you're running it in PyCharm without that piping, it seems like it does nothing. See [the project's wiki entry](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks/wiki/Ban-Brute-Force-Crackers) for an explanation on how this utility should be used.

SLOC stands for Source Lines of Code - the number of logical lines of code in the file (as opposed to the number of physical lines). See [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code) for some additional details about the differences between the two.

Comment: Specifically, it means that the file has executable status recorded in the git repository itself. It doesn't mean executing the file would actually work, nor do executable files need to have that status recorded in git.